# How to input a file into a subprocess without writing to a drive?

Tags: python, file, io, fortran

I am working on an optimizer for aircraft geometries and in the optimization process, it's needed to run a simulation in [AVL](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/avl/) (open source, Fortran), which takes the geometry as input and outputs useful data. Currently, the AVL part of the program works like this:

```py
def resultados_avl(aircraft, command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['avl'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    path = create_file(aircraft, False)
    if command[0] == 'alpha':
        out = process.communicate(bytes('load %s\noper\na a %.3f\nx\nst\n\nquit\n' % (path, command[1]), 'utf-8'))[0]
    if command[0] == 'trim':
        out = process.communicate(bytes('load %s\noper\na pm %.3f\nx\nst\n\nquit\n' % (path, 0), 'utf-8'))[0]
        
    process.terminate()
    output = out.decode('utf-8')
    results = dict()
    # Proceeds to do some RegEx "fun" in AVL's output
```

The problem with this method is the need to create a file for AVL to read. It is a simple text file with a geometry description, but as you know, reading and writing files is slow and performance is quite important in an optimizer.

My question: is there a way to get the input to AVL without writing to a drive?

I have thought of modifying the Fortran source code to take the input buffer from stdin, but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Well, theoretically it should be possible, just make it read from a different unit. But hard to tell you any details without the source code at hand. In Fortran you can remove the `open()` statement  and the `close()` statement and change the unit used for the `read` statement to read from the standard input instead. But you should try that yourself and come with some specific problems you encountered when trying that.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing! I Will answer this question myself later to help if someone comes across the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Vladimir F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721644/vladimir-f) pointed out, this can be done by removing the `open()` and `close()` statements and changing the unit used for the `read()` statement.

In the AVL source code, the geometry input is processed in the `ainput.f` file. The changes I made were commenting lines 72 and 1096, where the `open()` and `close()` statements are, and changing the unit in line 1152 to `*`, as follows:

```
20 READ (*,1000,END=80,ERR=90) LINE
```

Now, instead of reading from the specified file, AVL reads from stdin.